# Avoid repeated validators in class-validator

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I'm writing an API in Nest.js with several DTOs and I'm using class-validator for parameters` validation.

How can I avoid repeated validation like `IsString` and `IsNotEmpty`

```js
export class RolDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  key: string;
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to avoid. The `@IsNotEmpty()` has a specific meaning behind it, as does `@IsString()`.

Comment: What I'm saying is that, for example, `key` is defined to be a string and is not optional. So in theory Typescript already has the information needed to validate that `key` at least should be present and be a string.

Comment: Typescript has this information, yes, but `class-validator` (the validation library used by the build in `ValidationPipe`) does not. You could use another library, like `@deepkit/types`, but you'll need your own ValidationPipe for it

Comment: Ok, I will take a look at that. Thanks